# How set dynamic margin?

Tags: css, reactjs

i have one `div` and three child `div`, check out the code below

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     <icontag />
     <texttag />
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <icontag />
     <texttag />
   </div>
   <div class="child">
     <icontag />
     <texttag />
   </div>
</div>
```

each child tag composed of `icontag` and `texttag` and text tag is of dynamic height.

but, each icon tag margin must be same, even if text tag height is different.

for more explanation, refer to the picture.

[image]

as the above picture, the last text is multiline. so, last child tag height is diffent from other tags.

how can I do that?

Comment: Is there any restriction on the width of the texttag as well?

Comment: hmm.. is it same when text is enough long??

Comment: If your text is long you need to fit it either horizontally or vertically right? So, first, you need to restrict your text limit and then it would be easy to handle

Comment: i understand. but, client want to text tag is dynamic line(maximum 2 line). even if text has limit, some case text tag multi line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with `grid` and `flexbox`.

Try this, it might fit your needs

```css
.child {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
.parent {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 33% 33% 33%;
}

.child .icon {
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin-right: 20px;
}
.child p {
   max-width: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
.same {
   margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <p class="same">Same height</p>
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
         <div class="icon">1</div>
         <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bal dsfafda af afas fa faf af</p>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
         <div class="icon">1</div>
         <p>Bla bla bla</p>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
         <div class="icon">1</div>
         <p>Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bal dsfafda af afas fa faf af</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok. this is great answer. grid row template set each height, even text line is single line. but, if i want to set specific margin between icon tag, what should i do?

Comment: to increase or decrease the margin between the icon tags you need to put it on `child` div. like `.child { margin: 20px 0; }` for example. It increases the margin between the icon tags. is this what you need @sjm

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` on child items and `align-items: center` to vertically center the content.

Then use `padding` property (or `margin` could work as well) to have some space between `.child` items as in the following snippet.

```css
.child{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.icon{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #0000ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.text{
  flex: 1;
}

.child.third .icon{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child first">
     <div class="icon">1</div>
     <div class="text">Foo bar baz</div>
   </div>
   <div class="child second">
     <div class="icon">2</div>
     <div class="text">Foo bar baz</div>
   </div>
   <div class="child third">
     <div class="icon">3</div>
     <div class="text">Foo bar baz<br/>Foo bar baz</div>
   </div>
   <div class="child fourth">
     <div class="icon">4</div>
     <div class="text">Foo bar baz<br/>Foo bar baz</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But note that, if the texts are much longer than the icons, it could break the layout and you need to give static height to `child` items. But this way texts may overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding max-height to all child div..

```
.child {
  --
  --
  max-height: 300px;  // give max height as per your design
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: is it different margin by icon tag, if child tag has max-height?

Comment: If you giv max-height to childs, then all child divs can have a maximum-height of that value, and if the content is exceeding that value then scroll bar will be available inside that div..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   <div class="parent">
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 child">
         <icontag />
         <texttag />
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 child">
         <icontag />
         <texttag />
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 child">
         <icontag />
         <texttag />
       </div>
    </div>
```

You can set padding for child class.

```
padding: 10px;
```